# Can we use Sarrus' method for finding the determinant of matrix greater than $3\times3$?

Tags: matrices, determinant

Can [Sarrus' method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus) of finding the determinant be used for finding the determinant of matrices greater than $3\times3$, as I am unable to find any example of a matrix greater than $3\times3$ whose determinant is found by Sarrus' method?

I have tried many questions and Sarrus' method only works for $2\times2$ and $3\times3$ matrices. I have not read about Sarrus' method in any book but only from the internet, so I'm not sure about it.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers

Answer (score 2):

Nop. It **only** works for $\;3\times 3\;$ matrices. Of course, you can always develop bigger matrices' determinants by rows or columns until you reach matrices $\;3\times 3\;$ .

Of course, also $\;2\times 2\;$ matrices have a Sarrus's Method-like, but it is trivial there.

Comment: But see also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/105659/sarrus-rules-for-4-times-4.